# using Xpath selector after opening a modal on page?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xpath, import.io

Please take a look at one of the Google play apps , Those apps have something in footer of their pages called "Permissions".
When you click on "View Details" a modal pop-up appears .
I want to select that modal's content. How can I do that ?
I've tried this code :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'modal-dialog')]//div[contains(@class, 'permissions-container')]
```

But nothing happens, This xpath isn't working.
I've also used a Javascript code :

```
focusedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'modal-dialog')]"));
```

But as I'm using a windows app (Import.io desktop app) and it just accepts regex & xpath selectors. So how can I select the modal's content ?

Comment: @Abel I've already mentioned which scraper I'm using.
It's Import.io desktop app.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see, I have added it to the tags, it's your most important one, I sacrificed [tag:css3]. And unfortunately, I don't know about `import.io`. From its description, I doubt it can catch dynamically generated client-only DOM updates, but I can be wrong. If so, use another tool, one that supports GhostScript for instance.